# Encurtar endereço de um grupo de elementos com jQuery

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte **código**:

```
$("div.conteudo div.administrador form.administradorEdita")
```

Que é um

```
form
```

Quero fazer referência a um **label** dele;

```
var form = $("div.conteudo div.administrador form.administradorEdita");
```

Como seria?

```
form label#consulta
```

OU

```
$("form label#consulta")?
```

OU

```
$("form').label#consulta")?
```

?

Gostaria de pegar por exemplo o texto do **label**

Mas não  tem apenas esse elemento **label**.

São vários. Isso é um **formulário**.

Esse **formulário** tem vários campos aonde cada campo ganha um estilo próprio. Então:

```
$("div.conteudo div.administrador form.administradorEdita")
```

Seria um encurtamento de endereço para o formulário.

Preciso entende a dinâmica de como fazer para encurtar esse endereço.

Veja como fica gigante:

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  $("div.conteudo div.administrador form.administradorCadastra").on("submit", function() {

      var tipo = $("div.conteudo div.administrador form.administradorCadastra select#tipo").val();
      var nome = $("div.conteudo div.administrador form.administradorCadastra input[type=text]#nome").val();
      var login = $("div.conteudo div.administrador form.administradorCadastra input[type=text]#login").val();
      var senha = $("div.conteudo div.administrador form.administradorCadastra input[type=password]#senha").val();

      if ( tipo == "" ||
           nome == "" || 
           login == "" || 
           senha == "") {

          alert("Algum campo está vazio!");

          return false;

       } 

         $("div.conteudo div.administrador form.administradorCadastra input[type=submit].btnAcesso").css('display', 'none');
         $("div.conteudo div.administrador form.administradorCadastra img").css('display', 'block');

         $.post ("../_requeridos/cadastraAdministrador.php", {

             tipo    : tipo,
             nome    : nome,
             login   : login,
             senha   : senha

         }, function(retorno){


             $("div.conteudo div.administrador form.administradorCadastra input[type=submit].btnAcesso").css('display', 'block');
             $("div.conteudo div.administrador form.administradorCadastra img").css('display', 'none');

              if (retorno == 1) {
                resposta = "Cadastrado com sucesso!";
              } else {
                resposta = "Erro no cadastro";
              }
             $(".resposta").css("display", "block");
             $(".resposta").html(resposta);     

           }
          );

          return false;

    });

});
```

Comment: O label tem um id? Se tiver, a resposta do @DiegoMarques resolve tranquilo.

Comment: Fala Carlos, acho que a é ideia é essa mesmo, se vc colocar um ID vc não precisa desses caminhos todos. Vc busca o elemento direto pelo ID e pronto...

Comment: Então, pensei em algo tipo abaixo para encurtar o select#tipo". var tipo = $("this select#tipo").val();

Comment: ou var tipo = $(this) + $("select#tipo").val();

Answer (score 1):

Se o label tem um ID, e o ID deve ser único em um documento HTML, você pode pegar direto pelo ID. Exemplo:

```
$("#consulta");
```

Para pegar o texto você pode usar a função `"text()"`. Exemplo:

```
$("#consulta").text();
```

Comment: Então, esse é que é o problema. Não tem apenas esse elemento. São vários. Mas em cada endereço o estilo será diferente. Então não dá para fazer $("#consulta").text(); pois em alguns lugares mudarei o valor deste campo. Preciso entende a dinâmica de como fazer para encurtar esse endereço.